# How could I use The array texture in another class?

Tags: java, swing

I need to be able to use the variables in the array `texture[]` (which is located in the `Textures` class) in the `Board` class. But I can't figure out how I would go about doing that.

This is just me trying to figure out how to add `Textures` to things in Java, I am attempting to learn how to make games. So I'm very noobish haha.

This is the class that I want to use the `texture[]` array in.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel{
    
    public Board(){
        
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(texture[1], 0, 0, null);
        g.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 0, 50));
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.drawString(": FPS", 20, 50);
    }
    
    public void update(){
        repaint();
    }
}
```

This is the class that creates the `texture[]` array.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Textures {

    BufferedImage img;
    private int w, h;
    public int id[];
    public Image texture[];
    
    public Textures() throws IOException {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("Resources/Textures.png");
        img = ImageIO.read(url);
        w = 0;
        h = 0;
        for(int i1 = 0; i1 < 16; i1++){
            texture[i1] = img.getSubimage(w, h, 16, 16);
            id[i1] = i1;
            w += 16;
            h += 16;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As your `texture` variable is public, just do:

```
texturesClassInstance.texture;
```

in another way:

```
public class Board extends JPanel{

    public void someMethod(){

        Textures texturesClassInstance = new Textures();

        Image image1 = texturesClassInstance.texture[0];
        Image image2 = texturesClassInstance.texture[1];

        //do something with image1 and image2
    }
}
```

in the `Board` class, but the best is declare it as `private` and create a method like:

```
public class Textures {

    // more variables
    private Image texture[];

    // more code

    public Image[] getTextures(){
        return this.texture;
    }

}
```

Comment: I added the getTextures method and added an Image[] texture in Board.java, but whenever im in the Board class and type texture = Textures.getTextures(); it tells me that getTextures needs to be static but that just throws a ton more errors when i run the program.

Comment: You need an instance of Textures class, like `Textures texturesClassInstance = new Textures();` and do `texturesClassInstance.getTextures()`